# I am learning Batch - why am I having issue with setting an environment variable with other environment variables as its input? Mid String issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am sure this issue is something silly. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I want the variables, start and end to be used to set the mid string method I am using to set subStr. I have already read set /? with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo off
rem // First I will set all my varialbles...
set pleaStr=this is just a test. Please help me figure this out. I appreciate your help
set start=21
set end=-23
set subStr=%pleaStr:~start,end%
rem // The mid string method works normally. See!!
set subStrEasy=%pleaStr:~21,-23%
rem // Return extracted URL:
echo %pleaStr%
echo %subStr%
echo %subStrEasy%
```

The code above, does not work if I substitute the Environment Variables(ENV) start and end for their digit counterparts, 21 and -23.
when I `echo %subStr%` I get `pleaStr:~start,end`
where as `echo %subStrEasy%` gives me `Please help me figure this out.`

Perhaps environment variable cannot be used in this manner?

Comment: You may read a detailed explanation of this problem, and the way to solve it, at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 2):

And here is the solution using delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "pleaStr=this is just a test. Please help me figure this out. I appreciate your help"
set "start=21"
set "end=-23"
set "subStr=!pleaStr:~%start%,%end%!"
echo %subStr%
```